# Activate eye control without user interaction

Tags: windows-10, accessibility

Windows 10 supports eye control since version 1709 ([MS Support Website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043921/windows-10-get-started-eye-control)) using additional hardware, e.g. products from Tobii. There is a switch in `SystemSettings.exe` to activate the feature:

[image: screenshot system settings highlighted]

This sets the registry Key in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Input\EC\Enabled` to `1` when activated and to `0` when deactivated. But it also starts `ECApp.exe`, a small overlay window with control buttons and there are more things going on in the registry upon activation. What I need to do is to enable and disable this function from the commandline without user interaction.

What I've tried so far:

- I've tried to find a parameter to pass to the settings app but was unable to find something along those lines: `SystemSettings.exe -ActivateEyeControl`
- I also tried to set the mentioned registry value directly, but only setting the registry value doesn't do anything.
- Starting ECApp directly (`start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.ECApp_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`) causes the window to be look and behave wrong:
  [image: screenshot unusable ECApp]

Comment: What happens if you set the registry key and reboot the system?

Comment: After setting the registry key to `0` or `1` and doing a full reboot of the system, the eye tracking feature is correctly activated or deactivated and everything is working as expected. Unfortunately I have to accomplish this result without a reboot. Because the eye tracking feature doesn't work on the login screen, the user mustn't be logged out during the switching on/off process.